# Does stackmob support full-text search on their backend?

Tags: stackmob

Would like to build some stuff on top of StackMob, but couldnt find info. about is there any support to do full text search, search by text and order by distance and etc,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently support full text search, but we're considering it internally. We don't currently have a definitive answer if/when we'll have it, but if we do implement it, we'll provide good documentation on how to use it, as always.

All of our features are accessible through an OAuth 1/2 secured REST API, which is documented here: https://developer.stackmob.com/sdks/rest/api.

We also have documentation on our officially supported SDKs (Javascript, IOS, and Android).

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You're considering "if", not only "when" you'll have it?! I understand the challenges of such feature, but it has got to be #1 priotity, hans't it? Out of 10 projects where I would have liked to use StackMob, I had to go with Parse 9 times because of the lack of full text search